# function not returning as expected, returns before loop, but not after.

Tags: c

My function is not returning a string as expected, however, it does return before the for loop, and even returns a string if I place the return statement within the loop, but seems to ignore afterward.I'm at a complete loss as to why it doesn't return anything after the loop.  Here's my code:

```
char * encode(char *plaintext, char *key){
   char *message, *keyStr, *crypt;
   char str[0], letter;
   int keysize, i, num, n, plainInput[sizeof(plaintext)], 
   keyInt[sizeof(plaintext)], keyAndMessage[sizeof(plaintext)];
   unsigned size;

   size = (unsigned)strlen(plaintext);
   keysize = (unsigned)strlen(key);

  if(size != keysize){
     printf("the key size is: %d\n", keysize);
     printf("the plain text size is %d\n", size);
     return "Key and Plaintext Size Mismatch.";
  }

 message = malloc(size);
 keyStr = malloc(size);
 crypt = malloc(size);


for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

   // convert plaintext to ints
   letter = plaintext[i];                // could be any upper or lower case 

   str[0] = letter;                     // place char into new memory location
   num = strtol( str, NULL, 36 ) - 10;  // convert the letter to a number
   plainInput[i] = num;                 // store each number in an array -> 
   numInput

   // convert keys to ints
   letter = key[i];                     // could be any upper or lower case 
   str[0] = letter;                     // place char into new memory location
   num = strtol( str, NULL, 36 ) - 10;  // convert the letter to a number
   keyInt[i] = num;                     // store each number in an array ->

   keyAndMessage[i] = (keyInt[i] + plainInput[i]) % 27;

   // convert key to ascii for debugging only
    keyStr[i] = (char)keyInt[i]+65;

   // convert message to ascii text
   message[i] = (char)plainInput[i]+65;

   // combine message and key
   plaintext[i] = (char)keyAndMessage[i]+65;

}

printf("the original message is: %s\n", message);
printf("the key is             : %s\n", key);
printf("the crypt is           : %s\n", plaintext);
printf("the size of origin is: %lu\n", sizeof(message));
printf("the size of key    is: %lu\n", sizeof(key));
printf("the size of crypt  is: %lu\n", sizeof(plaintext));

return plaintext;
```

Comment: `sizeof(plaintext)` may != `strlen(plaintext)` and `key` not null terminated.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY beat me to it.  Sizeof tells you the size of the pointer, not the memory allocation or the strlen of the array.

Comment: It would be useful if you'd indented the code consistently, and included the terminating `}` for the end of the function.  Your explanation of the problem isn't very clear.  There are two return statements that I've spotted. If the first (where the sizes are compared) is not executed, then the second, at the end, must be executed — unless there's another hidden that I've not spotted.  I see that at least one comment wrapped the last word onto the next line so the code shown can't compile.

Comment: `int keysize, i, num, n, plainInput[sizeof(plaintext)], 
   keyInt[sizeof(plaintext)], keyAndMessage[sizeof(plaintext)];`...why, just why? What's the problem with declaration of one variable per line?

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY and for the help,  I misunderstood my application of sizeof vs strlen, which was preventing the function from returning anything after the loop was executed. I'm guessing this was due to a memory leak caused by the array exceeding it's allocated size, and overwriting the instruction to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BLUEPIXY makes one good point... probably the best solution to that is to define `size` earlier, then use that for your array sizes (use `size+1` to allow room for terminating null):

```
char * encode(char *plaintext, char *key){
    char *message, *keyStr, *crypt;
    size_t size = strlen(plaintext);
    int plainInput[size+1], keyInt[size+1], keyAndMessage[size+1];
        :
        :
```

but you have another problem as well: you've defined `str` to be an array of length 0, when it should be length 2... one for the letter, one for the terminating null character.

```
char str[2];
```

Though your conversion would be simpler (and more efficient) if you just used the character encoding directly:

```
num = toupper(letter) - 'A';  // convert the letter to a number
```

Also, you've allowed no space in your `malloc`s for a terminating null, and you have not put *in* the terminating null, so you are printing unterminated strings... which produces undefined behavior.  Change your `malloc`s as follows:

```
message = malloc(size+1);
keyStr = malloc(size+1);
crypt = malloc(size+1);
```

and be sure to terminate your strings before trying to print them:

```
message[size] = 0;
keyStr[size] = 0;
crypt[size] = 0;
```

Oh, and as pointed out earlier, sizeof will only give you the size of the pointers (in the `printf`s at the end), not the size of the string.  You need `strlen` there again.

And one more thing... your function tries to modify the string passed in (`plaintext`), which is  a bad idea because it could be a constant string. Better to put the new characters into a `malloc`ed buffer, as with `message`, et.al.  Also, you neglected to free your `malloc`ed buffers...memory leak!

Hopefully this will get you closer!

Comment: @SGeorgiades thanks for the clarification on the error of my ways.